# List with 2 arguments

Tags: c#, arraylist, int, arguments

I'm currently having this code:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(0);
list.Add(1);
list.Add(2);
list.Add(3);
color0 = list[1];
color1 = list[2];
color2 = list[3];
color3 = list[4];
```

Is there a possible way, this list could take 2 arguments in 1 element? What I mean is:

```
List<int,int> list = new List<int,int>();
list.Add(0,3);
list.Add(1,8);
color0=list[1][2]; //output 3
color1=list[1][1]; //output 0
color2=list[2][2]; //output 8
color3=list[2][1]; //output 1
```

Is there a possible was i can achieve something similar to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Tuple`:

```
var list = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
list.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 2));
```

For easier use you can create an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Add(this List<Tuple<int, int>> list, int x, int y)
    {
        list.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(x, y));
    }
}
```

Then you can add an element using this code:

```
list.Add(1, 2);
```

To access the items:

```
var listItem = list[0]; // first item of list
int value = listItem.Item2; // second "column" of the item
```

Comment: ..and access it as `color3 = list[7].Item1;`

Answer (score 1):

You can go with dictionary also if you have a key value pair:

```
static void Main()
    {
    Dictionary<int, int> dictionary =
        new Dictionary<int, int>();

    dictionary.Add(0,3);
    dictionary.Add(1,8);
    dictionary.Add(2, 13);
    dictionary.Add(3, -1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use a list like a matrix. In that case you might find [Math.NET](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Matrix.html) useful.